# Endpoints API - protorpc validation error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore, protorpc

I'm getting some weird errors from `protorpc` when I use endpoints. In this code:

```
class Application(EndpointsModel):

    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'name')

    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    roles = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
    updated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')

@API.api_class(resource_name="application")
class ApplicationApi(protorpc.remote.Service):

    @Application.method(http_method="GET",
                        request_fields=('id',),
                        name="get",
                        path="applications/{id}")
    def ApplicationGet(self, instance):
        if not instance.from_datastore:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException("Application not found.")
        return instance

    @Application.query_method(http_method="GET",
                              query_fields=('limit', 'order', 'pageToken'),
                              name="list",
                              path="applications")
    def ApplicationList(self, query):
        return query
```

when I call `application.get()` error is as follows: ([full trace here](http://pastebin.com/raw/c8Aj0Sj6)):

> TypeError: Can only copy from entities of the exact type Application. Received an instance of Application.

and for calling `application.list()` error is  as follows: ([full trace here](http://pastebin.com/raw/z6E3EF55)):

> ValidationError: Expected type `<class '.Application'>` for field items, found `<Application name: u'test'>` (type `<class '.Application'>`)

What could be causing this? My other models with pretty much the same code (just different properties) work fine.

Comment: Those traces look like you are using an instance of `Application` instead of the class(type) object `Application`. Are you sure you aren't using `Application()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Just double-checked, I'm not using it anywhere - all relevant code is in the question. I am extending a class `ApplicationApi(BaseRemoteService)`, but no mention of Application there, and there's a POST api method (which works...), but even if I remove all that I'm still getting the same errors with just the code from OP.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but prior to subclassing `EndpointsModel`, did `Application` subclass `ndb.Model`? Try looping through all `Application` entities and doing a `put` again on them. I'm thinking that the key you pass in fetches the entity but something about the inheritance chain is making the `__class__` fields not match.

Comment: You might be right. The weird thing is `Application` class didn't subclass anything other then `EndpointsModel`, but when I subclassed `class JsonModel(EndpointsModel)` (also did some other things in code, so can't be sure what exactly  is happening) it started working. I reverted back to `EndpointsModel` and it's still workig (; Guess the only way to deal with thiss kind of issues is to turn everything else off and isolate modules with problems...

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `class JsonModel(EndpointsModel)` to make it start working again.